# Spring mvc 3.2 and extjs 4.1.3 : do I have to define mvc:resources mapping for al requestMapping path?

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4

I have a problem using spring mvc 3 and extjs 4 or more precisely a problem of path when exjs try to load my controllers or my images.

The structure of my webapp is like this :

```
src
-- webapp
   -- app
   -- extjs4.1.3
   -- css
   -- icons
   -- WEB-INF
      -- jsp
   app.js
```

I have a controller annoted like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/init.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

It return a view name that match a jsp in my WEB-INF/jsp folder. This jsp load extjs files.

ViewResolver :

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>tiana Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Because my url pattern is "/", I had to make use of the mvc:resources magic tag available since spring 3.0.5 (approximatively) like this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/extjs-4.1.3/**" location="/extjs-4.1.3/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/app.js" location="/app.js" />
```

I know it could be better if I place all those things in a resources folder. I would have to write only :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

But I don't think it'll solve my problem

My jsp file is like this :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My jsp title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value="/extjs-4.1.3/resources/css/ext-all.css" />'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value="/css/myStyle.css" />'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/extjs-4.1.3/ext-all-debug.js" />'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/app.js" />"></script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
   </html>
```

First of all I had to write the references to my resources files using jstl tags. 
Without those tags, if I keep url like /myresource.xxx, the url will be

```
localhost:8080/myresource.xxx
```

And if I write myresource.xxx without the slash, it is

```
localhost:8080/mywebapp/path/myresource.xxx
```

But it works like this, any suggestion would be appreciated to skip the jstl dependency but it works.

My real problem is that my app.js will load extjs's controllers and for that it uses some kind of 'window.location' to construct the url. In my case, it will be

```
localhost:8080/mywebapp/path/app/controller/myController.js
```

but i'd like it to be

```
localhost:8080/mywebapp/app/controller/myController.js
```

I face the same kind of problem if I put an icon in my extjs files, the url will be

```
localhost:8080/mywebapp/path/icons/myIcon.png
```

and not

```
localhost:8080/mywebapp/icons/myIcon.png as expected.
```

I can solve this by adding

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/path/app/**" location="/app" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/path/icons/**" location="/icons" />
```

**But I can believe that each time I define a new requestMapping in a Spring mvc controller, "path2" for example, I'll have to define a corresponding mvc:resources mapping.**

I tried to define a global "baseUrl" javascript variable in my jsp file, prefixing the appFolder by this variable in  the app.js file and prefixing all icons and things used in extjs code by this variable but it's not either acceptable.

What have I missed ? I googled a lot and I came to this "/" url-pattern and mvc:resources method (which seems very clean for spring mvc webapp) but I cannot solve my "uri" problem (I don't know how the path generated by the requestMapping is called in real english).

Thank you so much if you can help me and if not, thank you for your time

Comment: Hi  Samuel  Gaiffe I am also facing the same problem . how did you resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put all of your resources (i'm not sure which of your contents is a static resource) in:

```
-- webapp
   --resources
      -- app
      -- extjs4.1.3
      -- css
      -- icons
   -- WEB-INF
   -- jsp
   app.js
```

then you define a single mapping:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

at this point you'll access the css folder for example using:

```
 <c:url value="/resources/css/myStyle.css" />
```

and any other of your paths in the same way or you can try by using (but not tested):

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and i suppose you'll access your css folder:

```
 <c:url value="/css/myStyle.css" />
```

Comment: Hi matteo and thank you for answering. As I said in my post, if I put all my resources in a resources folder, I don't think it's gonna change something to the fact that extjs will continue to use localhost:8080/mywebapp/path/resources/css/myStyle.css. There'll still be the false "path" but I'm gonna try your solution